# Traversing dependency parsing in dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, dictionary

I'm working on dependency parsing of text data and my algorithm is using an api from http://framenet.icsi.berkeley.edu.
I am receiving data in the form of dictionaries and the values are either empty or an array of dictionaries which again have some more dictionaries in their values.

This code is what I used to go a few steps deep in the dictionary.

```
keylist = parsed_tree.keys()
vallist = parsed_tree.values()
print(keylist)
print(vallist)
print("----------")
for k in vallist:
    for m in k:
        for l in m:
           print(l)
           print(m.values())
           print("/")
```

```
dict_keys([(3, 'ROOT', 'S')])
dict_values([[{(1, 'det', 'L'): []}, {(2, 'compound', 'L'): []}, {(6, 'nmod', 'R'): [{(4, 'case', 'L'): []}, {(5, 'det', 'L'): []}, {(9, 'nmod', 'R'): [{(7, 'case', 'L'): []}, {(8, 'amod', 'L'): []}, {(11, 'dep', 'R'): [{(10, 'det', 'L'): []}, {(13, 'nmod', 'R'): [{(12, 'case', 'L'): []}, {(14, 'cc', 'R'): []}, {(15, 'conj', 'R'): []}]}]}]}]}, {(16, 'punct', 'R'): []}]])

----------
(1, 'det', 'L')
dict_values([[]])
/
(2, 'compound', 'L')
dict_values([[]])
/
(6, 'nmod', 'R')
dict_values([[{(4, 'case', 'L'): []}, {(5, 'det', 'L'): []}, {(9, 'nmod', 'R'): [{(7, 'case', 'L'): []}, {(8, 'amod', 'L'): []}, {(11, 'dep', 'R'): [{(10, 'det', 'L'): []}, {(13, 'nmod', 'R'): [{(12, 'case', 'L'): []}, {(14, 'cc', 'R'): []}, {(15, 'conj', 'R'): []}]}]}]}]])
/
(16, 'punct', 'R')
dict_values([[]])
/
```

Look at:  (6, 'nmod', 'R')
Its values are more dictionaries. How do I write a general function to prune all the way deep in the dictionary and its values?

> **Edit:**  So from the answer here, I could get all the nodes of this tree, but in the tuples, we need to add the root node for all the nodes.

We got this from https://stackoverflow.com/a/54457756/10398679:

```
(3, 'ROOT', 'S')
(1, 'det', 'L')
(2, 'compound', 'L')
(6, 'nmod', 'R')
(4, 'case', 'L')
(5, 'det', 'L')
(9, 'nmod', 'R')
(7, 'case', 'L')
(8, 'amod', 'L')
(11, 'dep', 'R')
(10, 'det', 'L')
(13, 'nmod', 'R')
(12, 'case', 'L')
(14, 'cc', 'R')
(15, 'conj', 'R')
(16, 'punct', 'R')
```

So new tuple should look like:

```
(1, 'det', 'L', 3)
# In this tuple, 3 is the root node
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "prune"? If you just want to see everything in the dict you are already doing that.

Comment: does the order in which you traverse the dictionaries matter? I'd suggest you use some graph traversal algorithm (BFS/DFS) because that structure you have is basically a graph

Comment: @Phydeaux i want to simplify this dictionary structure so I can show the output into a dependency tree because my next step is to make all possible combinations of these dependent nodes. I’m going to cross match them with my annotations file

Comment: @KGS 1: the order of traversal doesn’t matter for now. 2: sure I don’t know much about graph traversing. Can you give me a head start? That would be a great help

Comment: @AhmedAli see my answer below for example of DFS

Comment: @Phydeaux sure let me try and run that. I’ll get back to you soon.

Comment: @AhmedAli so, for the example you posted here, what should the dependency tree look like? (if you could add this to the question rather than in a comment that would be great)

Comment: Okay so Now I know exactly what I need. We got all the nodes from the dependency tree but we lost their roots. We need the nodes with respect to their parent nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a recursive function to traverse the dict and run a function on each node (depth-first search, as suggested by KGS above).

```
def handle_tree(tree):
    for node in tree:
        handle_node(node)

        for child in tree[node]:
            handle_tree(child)


def handle_node(node):
    # Add some code here to do what you want with the node.
    print(node)
```

You can call it on your data structure with `handle_tree(parsed_tree)`.

Comment: Only thing is in the input the value of the root key is wrapped in an additional list that should be removed for this to work (is it possible to have multiple roots?) `parsed_tree[(3, 'ROOT', 'S')] = parsed_tree[(3, 'ROOT', 'S')][0]` . Also I'd say `for node in tree.keys()` to make it clearer but that's just me

Comment: @KGS I don't think it is, that's just how `dict.values` prints. `parsed_tree[(3, 'ROOT', 'S')]` is just one list, `[{(1, 'det', 'L'): []}, ...]`, and I loop through that with `for child in tree[node]`. It will also already handle multiple roots.

Comment: ah yes my bad I just copied that and ran it... I mean the output of `.values()` in op